# Send param to remote modal bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I want to send a form to a remote modal bootstrap,

```
 <?php
include ("project.php");
 ?>
          <div  id="tNew" class="inner cover" >
            <form class="objectif">
              <input  class="form-control" name="pName" required autofocus>
              <p class="lead"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#project" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" name="projectName" type="submit">Résoudre!</a>
              </p>
            </form>
         </div>
```

and here is project.php:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="project" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" name="pName"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know how? but I want to open another page "remote modal" and will be new/index.php
and I want to send the pName param to "project.php" and "new/index.php"!
can someone help ?